# POSTing XML via HTML Forms

Tags: php, html, xml, encoding, elgg

I am developing a web and want to make it so that the user can create some stuff POSTing XML data. For that purpose there is a `<textarea>` where the user can write (copy/paste) XML and submit it. The problem is that I am losing data: characters such as `<`, `>`, and I think others too, get lost.

Maybe it is a framework problem, not sure, I am using Elgg and receiving the data with `get_input()`.

**UPDATE1**: some code answering the comment:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://for.bar/slash" enctype="text/xml">
<input name="add" type="submit" value="Create"  />
</form>
```

to receive the data I use `elgg get_input()`

```
$data = get_input('data');
```

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2088880/1497596) to the question [How to post XML to server thru HTML form?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2088862/1497596), `text/xml` is *not* a permitted value for the `enctype` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i where to make a wild guess I'd say that there is some kind of auto-magical xss protection being used by get_input().  You could try doing a `print_r($_POST);` or perhaps elgg is "sanitizing"  all of $_POST as well.  In this case you may have to base64 encode the data with JavaScript before submitting the request.

Comment: You was right! Thx a lot. The get_input() function has a $filter_result = true parameter.

Comment: +1. Yeah, this results in the input being manged by `htmlawed_filter_tags`, which tries to make the input HTML whether it was supposed to be HTML or not. XSS “protection” at the input stage is **always the wrong thing**, and this is a particularly bad example of it. I strongly question the competence of the developers of this package.

Comment: That is a nasty "feature" that is all too common.  I agree that it is the wrong place for an xss filter.  I am glad I can help!

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN, the only standard values that should be used in form's `enctype` attribute are following:

- `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
- `multipart/form-data`
- `text/plain`

That being said, you can run into unpredictable situations having it to have value `application/xml`.

**Source:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype