# How to Pass an object to a REST Web Resource using Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

Iam a new bie in webservice.Please help me.I am trying to pass an object into webresource using Jersey Implementation.But i got error

```
"HTTP Status 405" and description is "The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource ()."
```

I mentioned the below object ,web resouce method,Html page

FruitBean:-

```
    @XmlRootElement(name="fruitbean")
    public class FruitBean {
        private long id;
        private String name;
        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
   }
```

FruitStore Service:-

```
@Path("fruitstore")
public class FruitStore {

    @PUT
    @Path("checkIDByObject")
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    public void loadObject(FruitBean bean){
        System.out.println("====================");
        System.out.println("Fruit ID"+bean.getId()+" Name"+bean.getName());

    }
}
```

Index.htm:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test Jax-RS Object</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="services/fruitstore/checkIDByObject" method="POST">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>ID:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="id"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>

    <td><input type="submit" Value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Iam trying to run this index.htm.But i got exception.How to pass an object into webresource method in Restfull webserice using jersey.Please Help me.

**Update :-**

```
FruitStore Service:-

    @Path("fruitstore")
    public class FruitStore {
    @POST
    @Path("checkIDByObject")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)

    public void loadObject(FruitBean bean){
        System.out.println("====================");
        System.out.println("Fruit ID"+bean.getId()+" Name"+bean.getName());

    }
}
```

FruitBean:-

```
@XmlRootElement(name="fruitbean")
public class FruitBean {


    private long id;

    private String name;
    @XmlAttribute
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

**Index.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test Jax-RS Object</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="services/fruitstore/checkIDByObject" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>ID:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="id"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>

    <td><input type="submit" Value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I got below message in the console

> SEVERE: A message body reader for Java type, class
>   com.service.fruitstore.FruitBean, and MIME media type,
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded, was not found

Please help me

Comment: have a courtesy to mention the reason of downvoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not sending xml to your controller. Check [How to post XML to server thru HTML form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088862/how-to-post-xml-to-server-thru-html-form).

Fruitbean: add annotations to the getters or fields

Edit:
you can test your webservice with [rest-client](http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/)

Edit2:

```
@Path("fruitstore")
public class FruitStore {

  @POST
  @Path("/checkobjectbyid")
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
  public void loadObject(FruitBean bean) {
    System.out.println("====================");
    System.out.println("Fruit ID" + bean.getId() + " Name" + bean.getName());
  }

  @GET
  @Path("/fruitbean")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
  public Response getFruitBean(){
    FruitBean fruitBean = new FruitBean();
    fruitBean.setId(1L);
    fruitBean.setName("name of fruitbean");
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(fruitBean).build();
  }
}
```

Use lowercase characters for path. (url's are lowercase)

Use correct Consume and Produces annotations.

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Part of web.xml

urls:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/PROJECTNAME/resources/fruitstore/checkobjectbyid

GET http://localhost:8080/PROJECTNAME/resources/fruitstore/fruitbean
```

Testing with rest-client

```
URL: http://localhost:8080/PROJECTNAME/resources/fruitstore/checkobjectbyid

METHOD: POST

CONTENT-TYPE: application/xml

CHARSET: UTF-8

BODY: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><fruitbean id="1" name="name of fruitbean"/>
```

Comment: Thanks.I doing as per your specify the url.But still i got "HTTP Status 415 ---The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method ().".Please help me

Answer (score 0):

First of all: in your `index.htm` : `method="POST"` and in the web-service code: `@PUT`. Then this is no a form action - this is just a body of your request. Try using rest-cliet as Err [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11932988/1235336) or a [Chrome cREST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/baedhhmoaooldchehjhlpppaieoglhml).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problems too. However, I did it a different way.
Instead of passing in an object (which would be easier, however, I am also doing this for learning purposes), I used the `@FormParam` annotation.

**HTML**

```
<form action="../{projectname}/{rest}/{resource}/findByIdOrName" action="post">
    <label>id</label>
    <input type="text" name="id" />
    <label>name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Find" />
</form>
```

**JAX-RS Resource**

```
@Path("/resource")
public class resource {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Path("findByIdOrName")
    public void findByIdOrName (@FormParam("id") int id, 
                                @FormParam("name") String name) {
        System.out.println("=======");
        System.out.println("id: " + id + " name:" + name);
    }
}
```

This is how I did it, it's easy and it works. As for models, I honestly do not know.. I'm more of a C#.NET guy and I'm trying to learn Java.