# ASP.NET: How to convert all form data to xml, then send xml to server?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a standard ASP web form like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content8" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<fieldset>
    <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text="First Name:"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tctFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" Text="Last Name:"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text="E-Mail:"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="lblPhone" runat="server" Text="Phone Number:"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
</fieldset>
</asp:Content>
```

I saw a post does the work: [How to post XML to server thru HTML form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088862/how-to-post-xml-to-server-thru-html-form) 
Here is the code:

```
$("#myform").submit(function(){
  var formjson = $('#myform').serializeArray();
  var formxml = json2xml(formjson);
  $.post("/collect.php", { 'data': formxml }, function(data){ 
    // callback logic
  });
  return false;
});
```

The result I got is already empty for 'serializeArray()'. 
So my question is:
1. how this jQuery code works with 'ContentPlaceHolder' instead of 'form'?
2. Does this jQuery code work with standard ASP control fields, or it has to be HTML field?
For example: I use  as text input, but HTML is:
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The placeholder is not actually an html tag 
First change this

```
<fieldset id='myfieldset'>
#bunch of tags
</fieldset>
```

in

```
$('#myform').serializeArray();
```

replace #myform with #myfieldset
Also you could just replace #myform with #Content8 but doing it on the fieldset will produce less clutter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Paul.
Actually I did add a  with id, then replace 'myform' with 'div id', but same thing. serializaArray() function returns nothing. I assume this function only recognize html attributes, not asp control attribute. Am I right? In order to use this function, do I need to replace all asp control elements to html elements first? If this is the case, how to replace asp:GridView? I do have something customization on this control.
Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I not sure you could use ASP.NET ContentPlaceHolder with JQuery SerializeArray.
According this [example](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) of SerializeArray, it should be a JQuery array of objects, like $(":input") meaning all the  controls

You have to check underlying html client-side code, and see what ContentPlaceHolder is convert to.
On my testing, with your code, I see that client-side 

is converted to

So you should use 
$(":input").serializeArray();

To recover data from your

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

I not sure you could use ASP.NET ContentPlaceHolder with JQuery SerializeArray.
According this [example](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) of SerializeArray, it should be a JQuery array of objects, like $(":input") meaning all the  controls

You have to check underlying html client-side code, and see what ContentPlaceHolder is convert to.
On my testing, with your code, I see that client-side

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tctFirstName" runat="server">
```

is converted to

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$tctFirstName" type="text" id="MainContent_tctFirstName" />
```

So you should use

```
$(":input").serializeArray();
```

To recover data from your `<asp:TextBox>`
I had check on my system, and its returns correct data on SerializeArray()

Hope it helps,